# Calculate income between days Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query to calculate a hotels income for every Thursday in a month but the total SUM has to be calculated for all the period between last weeks Friday and the next weeks Thursday.

Week 1 Friday -> Thursday Total income
Week 2 Friday -> Thursday Total income
and so on..

To explain it as simple as possible, I use the table RESERVATIONS to track the check-in and check-out date, number of guests and room type which is joined with the ROOM_PRICES table to calculate the prices.. How to calculate the SUM is not the problem, but to get that span between days is.

RESERVATIONS (reservation_ID, reservation_date, room_number,guest_id, number_of_guests, room_type, check_out_date)

ROOM_PRICE (room_type, price)

Expected output are two columns, Period and Total Income.

Total Income is the sum of all payments made by guests who spent their time in the hotel AND left on a week in between Friday and Thursday no matter if they spent two, three weeks in the hotel

```
    Period                  |Total Income 
   |-------------------------------------|
   |05.May.2017-11.May.2017 |       20000|
   |-------------------------------------| 
   |12.May.2017-18.May.2017 |       30000|
   |-------------------------------------|
   |19.May.2017-25.May.2017 |       12000|
```

And now the list continues..

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the `create table` statement for the table in question, some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: please provide the table structure of `Reservations` and `Room_Prices` for the better understanding of the scenario. Without it I am unable to get the context of your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE ROOM_PRICES(
  hotel_id INTEGER,
  day      DATE CHECK ( day = TRUNC( day ) ),
  price    NUMBER(8,2),
  CONSTRAINT room_prices__hotel_id__day__pk PRIMARY KEY ( hotel_id, day )
);

CREATE TABLE RESERVATIONS(
  hotel_id    INTEGER,
  check_in    DATE CHECK ( check_in  = TRUNC( check_in ) ),
  check_out   DATE CHECK ( check_out = TRUNC( check_out ) ),
  customer_id INTEGER
);
```

**Query**:

Subtract 4 from the date (so Friday maps to Monday) and then truncate to the iso-week (rounding to the Monday at the start of the week) then add the 4 days back on and add another 6 days to get the Thursday:

```
SELECT TRUNC( day - 4, 'IW' ) + 10 AS Thursday_of_week,
       r.hotel_id,
       SUM( price ) AS 
FROM   room_prices p
       INNER JOIN reservations r
       ON (   r.hotel_id =  p.hotel_id
          AND p.day      >= r.check_in
          AND p.day      <  r.check_out )
GROUP BY
       r.hotel_id,
       TRUNC( day - 4, 'IW' ) + 10
```